# How do I install the rtl8188ce driver in ubuntu 18.04.4 if I don't have an ethernet port

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, lenovo, ethernet

I have a Lenovo ideapad s130-11igm with a rtl8818ce wifi card, but there are no rtl8818ce drivers for ubuntu except for in github.

I can't access the internet in order to install these drivers because the Lenovo Ideapad s130-11igm **has no ethernet ports**.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: If you have a USB-Ethernet https://www.google.com/search?q=USB-ethernet adapter, you can use that.

Comment: You might also be able to use tethering with your phone. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: put the files on a USB stick

Comment: The two easiest ways is to use windows if dualbooted or find another near by computer, friends or library, and download and copy to USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

Try USB tethering with your phone.

Now, you might worry about using data... Not to fear! Connect to WiFi, turn on USB tethering, and then turn off data! 
Most phones should keep tethering on, but it will use WiFi instead of your precious cellular data!

If this works, you can go ahead and install git then run that command on the git page...

If that doesn't work, download the repo .zip to your phone and copy it to your computer desktop (over MTP or PTP or however you can) and install the driver.

Comment: my phone is in repair, thx anyway!

Comment: Hmmm... You can transfer files via Bluetooth between computers, burn the files to a CD/DVD/blueray, or just use a USB drive... I reccomend using a CD-RW or DVD-RW if going the disk route, since those are ReWritable. Definitely just use a USB stick if possible, though.

Answer (score 0):

On a internet connected computer, go to the Github repo that you want to use (I assume it's this [one](https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver)) Click the button that says Clone or Download and download the repo as a zip file. Unzip the file and then put it onto a flash drive. Put the flash drive into your computer that has no driver and copy the files over.

Then cd into the folder (instructions are for the Github repo linked above):

```
cd rtl8188ce*
```

Make the installer executable:

```
chmod +x install.sh
```

Run the installer:

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

If the automatic installer doesn't work, follow [these](https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver#manual-installation) instructions to install the driver manually.

If you run into dependency problems, install gcc and git manually and then run the installer again.

To install gcc, click [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gcc) on an internet connected computer, scroll to the bottom and download the correct package for your computer (most likely amd64). Download the .deb file onto a usb driver and then copy the file to your home directory of your computer that needs the driver. Install gcc by typing the following into terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i gcc*.deb
```

To install git, click [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/git) on an internet connected computer, scroll to the bottom and download the correct package for your computer (most likely amd64). Download the .deb file onto a usb driver and then copy the file to your home directory of your computer that needs the driver. Install git by typing the following into terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i git*.deb
```

All the dependencies should be installed, so when you run ./install.sh again the installation should be sucessfull.

Comment: thx i will try it!

Comment: i did what you said but it keeps failing

Comment: @DylanBevan Can you post what the output is after you run ./install.sh (and it fails?) Have you made the installer executable? Are you using the Github repo linked above?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, I followed the instructions, but .install.sh fails because it requires dependencies gcc, git, etc. that I don't have and cannot install, because I can't get any kind of connection working.

Comment: @user2360490 I edited my answer to include how to install git and gcc offline. Are there any other dependencies that is needed?

Comment: hey thanks! In the Git repo you link to, for dependencies it says: `apt-get install gcc build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r)`. When I tried manually installing things before, it just kept on throwing more unmet dependencies at me. `sudo dpkg -i gcc*.deb` tells me I need `gcc-7`.

Comment: @user2360490 Is your problem solved then?. You can go to https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/gcc-7 and download and install gcc-7 by issuing sudo dpkg -i ggc-7*.deb. Manually all the dependecies really is a pain.

Comment: No, it's not solved at all. I have so far not been able to install a single thing, it is just unmet dependencies all the way down. BTW, I'm using focal, is there any reason you're linking to bionic repos?

Comment: I updated the links to make them for focal. FYI you can manually download any package typing https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/[name of package here eg. git] into your web browser. Could you give me a list of unmet dependencies?

Comment: I'd love to make a list of unmet dependencies, but every time I try to install some package, it just gives me more. Is there a way to generate a list of all dependencies? I am trying `apt-cache rdepends` but so far with no success.

Comment: @user2360490 I guess you need to install every package manually then? Seems like lots of work. There must be a better way..

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I appreciate your help, and will keep looking for a solution.

Comment: Just top let you know, I managed to solve the problem and posted my solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230020/my-computer-wont-connect-with-anything-at-all-bluetooth-wifi-tethering-is-the/1230682).