# Installing USB Wifi w/ RealTek RTL8812AU

Tags: drivers, package-management, realtek-wireless

I have a TP-Link Archer T2U Nano Wifi USB Stick and am trying to get it to work on Ubuntu 20.04.

`lsusb` shows it as:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:011e TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter
```

Found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149117/tp-link-ac600-archer-t2u-nano-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04), but without the stick I don't have internet. The [dkms package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/dkms) has quite a few dependencies, and I assume these dependencies will have there own dependencies as well. So I can't just download the package and copy it over to my Ubuntu machine with a USB stick. And then maybe these require updating other packages...

What are my options here? Or do I really have to download and install dmks and all its dependencies by hand?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: You can alsway connect to internet using your phone as a USB modem to install dependencies.

Comment: Uh.. didn't I show the `lsusb` output? What more do you want?

Comment: hm.. I guess the phone is an option...

Comment: No, you didn't. You copied only a part that seemed important to you ;-) It doesn't show the chip model. How did you know it is RTL8812AU?

Comment: @user1785730 Maybe this might help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230020/my-computer-wont-connect-with-anything-at-all-bluetooth-wifi-tethering-is-the/1230682

Comment: Does your PC not have an Ethernet port?

Comment: @K7AAY `-v` is not needed. `lsusb` will show VID and PID.

Comment: @Pilot6: Better? Actually I don't. Does the rest I added determine this?

Comment: It really is `rtl8821au`. But that driver should work.

Comment: @Pilot6: Just curious, how can you tell from this?

Comment: `2357:011e` is the clue.

Comment: Interesting. Where can one lookup the 2357:011e to rtl8821au relationship?

Comment: In google as an option ;-)

Comment: And here https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8812au-1/blob/v5.3.4/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c you can make sure the driver is correct.

Comment: Hm.. it seems to be RTL8821. But the RTL8812 driver handles this as well?

Comment: Yes, it does as you can see. If it goes wrong, update your question. I will reopen it and see what can be done.

Comment: I don't agree this is a duplicate. I even linked to that question. Although the comments dealt mainly with the driver issue, the question really was about: how to install the driver without internet?

Comment: Do you really expect an answer: "Use your phone"?